# scrollbar widget for gui

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have created a Tkinter program and has 3 frames that exceed window size. Till now only 2 frames are visible on the GUI and I guess the 3rd one is below it. I need a scrollbar for the window. So any solutions?

```
def InsertValue(self,window = None,num=None):
    self.insert = Tk()
    self.insert.title("New Order")

    self.my_canvas=Canvas(self.insert)
    self.my_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    self.y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.my_canvas,orient=VERTICAL,command=self.my_canvas.yview)
    self.y_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.y_scrollbar.set)
    self.my_canvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: self.my_canvas.config(scrollregion= self.my_canvas.bbox(ALL)))
```

after that I have 3 frames in the canvas.

Comment: You can make a canvas on the size of window and then put these items on the canvas and add a scrollbar to it.

Comment: I am having a problem doing that...can u help with the code

Comment: Show what you have tried? So I just have to fix the problem with the code there, rather than giving an entire new example.

Comment: I have shared the code

Comment: Yea, there will be a canvas with a scrollbar now, where are you inserting the frames to this.